# Sharepoint Replace Item Permissions Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, form-library

Working with :SharePoint 2010, SharePoint Designer 2010, InfoPath 2013
Type: Form Library

Setup: 
- List itself gives users "full access". 
- Upon creation of an item, a workflow is triggered that replaces that items permissions to only include the creator, who it was assigned to, and a couple of admins. None of these people are assigned to a group.

Problem:
1. User #1 (first person to create items) has no problem adding new items. 
2. User #2 (second parson to create items) creates item by filling out necessary form, and upon submission gets an error: 
*The form cannot be submitted to the specified SharePoint list or document library. The SharePoint location may be read-only or you may not have permissions to access it.
An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. 
Log ID:5567
Correlation ID:3c2a316b-3b2a-4b56-9370-f56d50b6587c*

Deleting all items and stopping the workflow allows all users to add items.

Workflow is built as follows:

Impersonation Step:
Replace FULL CONTROL of item in CURRENT ITEM

This is meant to remove all permissions from the item ONLY and give myself, my supervisor, the person who created it, and the person it's assigned to full permissions.

Full disclosure: I do have an autonumbering mechanism in place.

Comment: After the firstitem workflow is completed, are the list permissions the same as before?